# phpmyadmin on ubuntu cloud server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just bought a cloud server from hetzner cloud and I am wondering how can I install phpmyadmin on it.

I extract the phpmyadmin rar and put it on via FTP. But when I go to `http://IP/phpmyadmin/setup` it tells me `connection refused`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The official phpMyAdmin distribution doesn't occur in a rar file, so to start with if you want a manual installation, I'd go to the official page at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and start there because who knows what is going on in the rar file you have.

Aside from that, there are Ubuntu packages you could use if you prefer to use the package manager, if it isn't already part of your distribution's package list you can add the PPA (see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu for details).

For most people, the packaged version is the solution I'd recommend, but if you want to install it manually then you should start with the official download and see if you still have trouble.

Further, to be more direct about the specific question you've asked, please look in the webserver error log and see if there are any hints; also do any other pages work correctly on that server? Can you access `http://IP/phpmyadmin/` or `http://IP/` ?